# How to configure VirtualBox to route through tor?

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, tor

How can I configure VirtualBox to route all network access of a guest OS through TOR? My host system is running Linux, and I've already set up TOR on it.

Comment: What is the host operating system? Have you already set up TOR on it?

Comment: The host system is Linux and tor is set up and running fine on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is a tor middlebox. There seems to already be documentation on how to do this.

http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-a-tor-middlebox-routing-all-virtualbox-virtual-machine-traffic-over-the-tor-network

This might be different depending on what network manager you use.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be what I was looking for. But what happens to the upd traffic from the vm? Is it just discarded?

Comment: Umm, you'll have to ask somebody else about that. I don't have that much experience with tor.